# failing to delete of files, after AoT build

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, webpack, mean-stack

When i run the build:prod command from my package.json file, the compilation builds succesfully, but fails to delete .ngsummary.json files aswell as all .ngfactory.ts files

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
  "@angular/cli": "^1.4.2",
  "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
  "@angular/upgrade": "^4.4.3",
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
  "core-js": "^2.5.1",
  "debug": "~2.6.3",
  "express": "^4.15.5",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "hbs": "~4.0.1",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^8.0.1",
  "mongoose": "^4.11.12",
  "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.6",
  "morgan": "~1.8.1",
  "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
  "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
  "webpack": "^3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
  "@types/node": "6.0.45",
  "angular-router-loader": "^0.6.0",
  "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
  "del-cli": "^0.2.0",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
  "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
  "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
  "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
  "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
  "typescript": "^2.5.2",
  "webpack": "^2.2.1",
  "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Specifically refering to this command:

```
"build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'"
```

When the build comes out successful, My project gets cluttered with .ngsummary.json & ngfactory.ts files, which should be deleted by the build:prod script. All the other file types gets deleted (they don't show up in my working directory, but only in the target directory).

I guess i should include my webpack.config files - These are divided in 3:

webpack.config.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }]
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    }
};
```

webpack.config.dev.js:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        publicPath: "/js/app/",
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: {
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }},
                    {loader: 'angular2-template-loader'},
                    {loader: 'angular-router-loader'}
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
});
```

webpack.config.prod.js:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge.smart(commonConfig, {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular-router-loader?aot=true'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false
        })
    ]
});
```

I am using windows 10 if it has anything to do with OS permissions - which i doubt, but you never know.

---

EDIT: 
Think i should add tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.aot.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./public/js/app"
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es5",
    "dom"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem, solution is tsconfig.aot.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
 "module": "es2015",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"outDir": "./public/js/app"
},
 "typeRoots": [
"node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
 "es5",
 "es6",
 "es2015",
 "es2017",
 "dom",
 "scripthost"
],
"angularCompilerOptions": {
 "skipMetadataEmit": true
 }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es5",
  "es2015",
  "es2017",
  "dom",
  "scripthost"
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: in my example, building production was done normal, but output app folder was empty

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues getting my production build to cleanup after success.  My sample project is very similar to the OP.  The big difference is that I am using the latest Angular version which is currently 7.2.9.  I did not change the lib section as suggested.  I removed the single quotes from each path description.  So instead of this (from my package.json):

```
"build:prod": "del-cli dist && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail 
&& del-cli 'src/**/*.js' 'src/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'src/app/**/*.js.map'
```

I did this:

```
"build:prod": "del-cli dist && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail 
&& del-cli src/**/*.js src/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts src/app/**/*.js.map
```

This did work for me.  I realize there is quite a gap between Angular 4 (OP's version) and Angular 7 (my version), however my issue seemed identical to the OP.  My guess is that del-cli lib has not changed significantly in a while.

Added relevant package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/router": "^7.2.9",
"@angular/upgrade": "^7.2.9",
"core-js": "^2.6.5",
"rxjs": "^6.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ngtools/webpack": "^7.3.6",
"@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
"@types/node": "^11.11.3",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
"del-cli": "^1.1.0",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
"typescript": "^3.2.4",
"webpack": "^4.29.6",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
"webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
}
```

Note: I am running on a windows 10 system.